# How can I specify Xamarin version in Appveyor build process?

Tags: xamarin, appveyor

We use Appveyor for our continuous integration and it automatically includes the latest Xamarin version when creating the build vm. 
However, all developers and the mac host for building the iOS app are using the previous version. We are unwilling to upgrade at this point as multiple projects are due to be released within the next few weeks and these big upgrades invariably add days of delay.

As such, it would be great if someone could show me how I can specify the Xamarin version when creating the build Vm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to appveyor support and they replied with this partial solution:

I’m afraid we can’t have multiple versions of Xamarin as it ties pretty hard into Visual Studio environment. Maybe in the future they will do it more portable.

You can rollback to the previous build worker image for now. Add `image: Previous Visual Studio 2015` to your appveyor.yml or select it on UI (Environment tab of project settings) if you don’t use yml. Of course, it’s not a long term solution as current image will become previous during the next update. It maybe Xamarin issue or the app should be upgraded to Xamarin Latest version.